# copy all file source to destination then remove all files from source in php

Tags: php

just i'm trying to copy all file source to destination and then remove all file from source in php.

here is my code:

```
function rcopy($src, $dst) {
    if (is_dir($src)) {
        $files = scandir($src);

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            if ($file != "." && $file != "..")
                rcopy("$src/$file", "$dst/$file");
        }

        array_map('unlink', glob($src."/*"));
    } else if (file_exists($src)) {
        copy($src, $dst);
    }
}
```

copy working well but file not deleted from source. please help

Comment: What does `rcopy` do exactly? I can't find it in the documentation.

Comment: Are the `$src` and `$dst` on the same machine? Different machines? Do you have access to delete files on the `$src`? Are you receiving any errors?

Comment: @crush same like `copy`

Comment: @crush..yes both are on same machine and i have permission to access and delete.

Comment: Well, then I don't see any reason why this wouldn't work, but I do think that @NanheKumar's solution would be a more optimal way of deleting the files. Currently, you are iterating the directory files twice.

Comment: It's possible that `$src."/*"` is producing a string that is pointing nowhere. Can you show us the output of `echo $src . "/*"`?

Comment: `$src` output is `mydirectry/structure/*`

Comment: I'm not sure. All I can think is that some reason it's not pointing to the right directory. I'd give @NanheKumar's solution a try.

Comment: I don't see why it could cause an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$files = scandir($src);
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            rcopy("$src/$file", "$dst/$file");
            unlink("$src/$file");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To delete directory use [rmdir](http://php.net/rmdir), unlink using to delete files.
Note: The directory must be empty, and the relevant permissions must permit this.

Comment: He wants to delete files, not directory.

Comment: But in code, he checks is_dir($src), if true he call rcopy recursively.

Comment: @Starfox He gets a list of all the files, then iterates over that list, and calls rcopy on each file individually. It doesn't seem like his intent would be to remove the directory itself.

Comment: Yes, but I mean a case, when his folder will contain another folder.